# Problems with QProcess after fork() and execv()

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, fork

I have a program that launches a worker process, waits for it to finish (listens to `SIGCHLD` signal) and then launches another worker process. Inside my worker processes I launch a `QProcess` that calls another program. In my test case I call `touch` - the standard Linux command.

I use `fork()` and `execv()` to launch worker processes.

The problem is that `QProcess` finishes successfully in the first worker process only. After new worker processes are spawned, `QProcess` never says that it was finished. `touch` command itself does its job fine all the time. But in all worker processes except for the first one it becomes a zombie in the end.

Here's a minimal test program:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

#include <signal.h>
#include <wait.h>

void spawnWorkerProcess();
void launchQProcess();
void catchSigChild(int i);
void execChild();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    if (argc > 1) // worker process
    {
        launchQProcess();
    }
    else // main process
    {
        if (signal(SIGCHLD, catchSigChild) == SIG_ERR)
        {
            qFatal("could not attach to SIGCHLD");
        }

        spawnWorkerProcess();

        return app.exec();
    }
}

void spawnWorkerProcess()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        qCritical() << "FORK ERROR";
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        /* the child process */
        execChild();
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        qWarning() << "FORK OK";
    }
}


void
execChild()
{
    unsigned i = 0;
    const char **argv = new const char *[3];

    QByteArray ba = qApp->applicationFilePath().toLocal8Bit();
    argv[i++] = ba.data();
    argv[i++] = "worker";
    argv[i++] = 0;

    qWarning() << "execv ..."  << argv;
    execv(argv[0], const_cast<char *const *>(argv));
    qWarning() << "execv OK";

    delete[] argv;
}

void catchSigChild(int i)
{
    qCritical() << Q_FUNC_INFO << i;

    pid_t cpid;
    int stat;

    while ((cpid = waitpid(0, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {
        static int counter = 0;

        counter++;

        if (counter < 5)
        {
            qDebug() << "SPAWN:" << counter;
            spawnWorkerProcess();
        }
        else
        {
            qCritical() << "RESPAWN LIMIT REACHED! Bye-bye!";
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
void
launchQProcess()
{
    QProcess pr;

    qWarning() << "start QProcess " << qApp->applicationPid();
    pr.start(QString("touch /tmp/test/%1").arg(qApp->applicationPid()), 0);

    if (! pr.waitForFinished(3000))
    {
        qWarning() << "QProcess FAIL" << qApp->applicationPid() << pr.state() << "\n";

        delete (int*) 1; // we don't want to wait for QProcess timeout, so doing crash
    }
    else
    {
        qWarning() << "QProcess OK" << qApp->applicationPid() << pr.state() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt, but it seems like you're only catching SIGCHLD on the main process. Have you tried attaching a listener for that signal before calling spawnWorkerProcess inside catchSigChild?

Comment: @Austin Mullins: `SIGCHLD` in the main process works fine. My handler is always executed when a worker process dies. The problem is with `QProcess` whose internal manager doesn't get`SIGCHLD` from `touch` command.

Comment: Why do you have the statement `delete (int*) 1;`?

Comment: @RobbieE I'm doing a crash beacause dont't want to wait for `QProcess` timeout. Anyway it can be replaced with `exit(1)`.

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to make glibc calls from within signal handlers. You're spawning from within your SIGCHLD handler, and I wonder if that's hosing up your signal handlers. Try setting a global flag and have main spawn new workers. You may also try resetting your CHLD handler to the default ignore after forking so any handler changes don't propagate to the execv.

Comment: @CDahn Thank you! Moving new spawnings from signal handler to main fixed my problem. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it. Also I would appreciate if you could add some sources on why it is "generally considered bad form to make glibc calls from within signal handlers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never make calls into glibc from within a signal handler. Handlers are called asynchronously, which means they can interrupt system calls. Those calls may not be reentrant. To learn more about this, check the following page:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Nonreentrancy.html